# To respond positively

Tags: sentence-choice, personal-pronouns

Suppose the following scenario; which one of the listed answers would work here? '1' or '2' or both sound natural to you as natives?

> Person B) Hey Andy, I finally proposed to her!
>
> Person A) Really? Cool; and what was her answer?
>
> Person B)
>
> 1) - She had a positive response.
>
> 2) - His response was positive.

Comment: 1) The object of B's affection is ambiguously gendered. 2) I'd say *S/he said 'Yes'!*

Comment: Hi @StoneyB . You were right and sorry for the mistake. I remember once when I was talking to a native, he used such a structure; so my question is that 1) is it possible to answer in this way at all? 2) if yes, which one sounds more natural to you?

Comment: You need to fix 2), too. ... Neither is particularly "natural":  a "positive response" is the sort of phrase you'd use in a technical paper.

Comment: If she were a droid, you could say her response was affirmative. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IPAOxrH7Ro

Comment: A *positive response* is optimistic but not *Yes*. But I would not use it in this kind of situation (maybe, "getting a positive response to a job offer" would be more appropriate). I would go with a simple "Yes", "Maybe", or "No way". Or just go with what she actually said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that "His/Her response was positive" is the better of the two.

However, it kind of sounds formal and stiff.

In everyday conversation one may just report the action as "He/She said yes".

Answer (score 0):

To me "His response was positive" sounds better. I'd like to point out that it would sound even more natural to say "He said yes".